# How to reinitialize the view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

i have one view with NStab, at tabindex0 i have some buttons here i am hiding my buttons when i pressed on each one. at last button i am hiding that button and go to tabindex1. in tabindex1 i have a button called return.when i press that button i want to go my tabindex0 and display my buttons as it is.i.e i want to reinitialize my tabindex0.

Comment: what the meaning of sathiyama puriyala

Comment: i cant able to understand your question.

Comment: ok  i have one view with NStab, at tabindex0 i have some buttons here i am hiding my buttons when i pressed on each one. at last button i am hiding that button and go to tabindex1. in tabindex1 i have a button called return.when i press that button i want to go my tabindex0 and display my buttons as it is.i.e i want to reinitialize my tabindex0.. i think you got some idea.....

Comment: still not understand my problem or my question? sathiyama puriyala

Comment: @hemaraju: i understand your question but i dont know about the mac application. i am working on iphone only. sorry...

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to reinitialize a view, unless you are dealing with a case where you can remove it entirely and recreate it by reloading the nib file.

In this case, you just want to call setHidden:NO on all of the buttons. Something like:

```
for (NSView *subview in [[[myTabView tabViewItemAtIndex:0] view] subviews])
    [subview setHidden:NO];
```